# PostgreSQL ODBC connection doesn't recognise my schemas

Tags: postgresql, connection, odbc, tatukgis

I am working with postgreSQL 9.6, postgis 2.3 and tatukgis viewer 3. I can succesfully connet using ODBC driver but I can't load a layer, an error is sent : "public schema doesn't exist". [image: erro message]

It seems like it can't read my table.

Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: Can you share your connection string?

Comment: Thanks for your help Jim Jones but found the solution. I just update my tatuk viewer version and all thing goes well. I can now display and handle my postgresql objects.